# what mean a p-value above 0.05 doing an ANOVA?

Tags: r, anova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to interpret F- and p-value in ANOVA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12398/how-to-interpret-f-and-p-value-in-anova)

I found that I can use ANOVA also for ONE Model, doing something like:

```
> anova(lm(a~b))
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: a
           Df   Sum Sq   Mean Sq F value    Pr(>F)    
b           1 0.002679 0.0026791  11.191 0.0009001 ***
Residuals 398 0.095282 0.0002394                      
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

I know that ANOVA check the means BUT what test is that if I use only ONE model?
If the p.value is above 0.05 it means that the regression fit good?

Comment: Please undertake some research before asking questions.  The meaning of a p-value is extensively documented and heavily discussed even on this site.

Comment: @whuber I KNOW what is a "p-value" but I don't know why (IN THIS CASE) Is usefull because i'm not comparing groups, I only used one linear model...so what "means" ANOVA is checking ??

Comment: A prior answer I believe should be satisfactory for this question, [Logic behind the ANOVA F-test in simple linear regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8237/logic-behind-the-anova-f-test-in-simple-linear-regression/8247#8247).

Comment: Thanks, @Andy.  There are [many questions on this site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=anova+%2Bp-value) that could serve as a duplicate of this one (the search brings up 43 of them).

Comment: Yes @whuber, I agree. To Dail, it is good practice to comb through the related questions on the site. In this instance, just perusing the questions tagged [tag:anova] would turn up a wealth of potential resources and explanation for similar questions.