# How can Degrees of Freedom increase for Mixed Effects Model Comparison w/ Chi Square?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, model-comparison

I'm using `lme4` for mixed effects linear regression, and I'd like to compare two models using `anova()`. However, I'm perplexed by the `Df` column. If I have two nested models, where the second has more independent variables than the first, how can the second model have more degrees of freedom?

One example can be found at this question: [How to interpret ANOVA output when comparing two nested mixed-effect models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121661/how-to-interpret-anova-output-when-comparing-two-nested-mixed-effect-models)

Another example (sorry about the formatting)

`Df  AIC   BIC  logLik   deviance  Chisq Chi Df Pr(>Chisq)
aov_models$base                 7 11862 11907 -5924.2    11848

aov_models$augmented           13 11786 11869 -5880.1    11760 88.113      6  < 2.2e-16 ***`